# place a <div> on another<div>

Tags: html, css

i want the div which contains content holder to partially cover the div which contains the building image.

```
<div style=" background-position: -23px; height: 247px; background-image: url('/6.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; "></div>
<div style=" min-height: 450px; width:100%;" align="center" >
<div style=" width:85%; margin-top:200 ">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to know more information about what these divs are inside. The first answer gives `fixed` positioning as a solution, but that's only if you want to fix something to the window pane (as opposed to the context of some parent container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the tag    **position: absolute;**     on the content I want to move like this:

```
#contentholder{
position: absolute;
margin-left: 100px
margin-top: 200px
}
```

but make the margins relevant to where you want that content to go.

Answer (score 0):

I use this...

```
#overlay {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #333333;
 //Cross-browser opacity below
 -moz-opacity:.80;
 filter:alpha(opacity=80);
 opacity:.80;
 z-index: 10000000;
}
```

Comment: #overlay {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
} i used this much and it worked..thnx

Comment: but with position:fixed, scroll bar doesn't appear in browser. It does when position:absolute.